# WordPress - get_posts by meta_query where key CONTAINS certain string

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to run a PHP get_posts query in WordPress to target posts with a meta data key that CONTAINS a certain string. The issue is, I don't know the full key name as it is created independently by another plugin but all keys have in common that they start with "_cegg_data".

Sometimes the field will be called "_cegg_data_ae_googlecom", other times "_cegg_data_ae_youtubecom" and so on.

Is there a way to run a query posts with a meta_query that contains "_cegg_data" in the key (value unknown as well)?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_cegg_data{{anything here}}'
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/221760, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/159426

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks - the first link was very helpful and led me to a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `LIKE` comparison for partial string macthing.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_cegg_data',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => '_cegg_data%'
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts($args);
```

The `%` will work as a wildcard matching any number of characters, so this will get every product post where the key starts with `_cegg_data`.

Comment: They do not want a partial match on the _value_, but on the key _name_.